# Move user folders to secondary drive in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I've got a notebook with a rather small SSD and a large secondary HDD. Now I want to install Windows 10 so the Userprofiles (c:\Users) are stored on the secondary HDD, since there is more space.

I will install Windows afresh, so I won't need to take care of existing files.

One way would be to move every single user data Folder (documents, Images, Videos, ...) to the HDD, but I'd rather move the full thing instead, if possible.

Any ideas?